# UNION or INNER JOIN PL/SQL query

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Trying to make a query with 2 tables being referenced, but apparently I'm getting inappropriate `INTO`s for the second table select. Can I even use a `UNION ALL` statement here or how would I do an `INNER JOIN` statement? Example of my code below:

```
DECLARE
 v_CVar1 NUMERIC(1);
 v_CVar2 CHAR(4);
 v_SVar1 NUMERIC(1);
 v_SVar2 CHAR(4);

BEGIN
 SELECT CVAR1, CVAR2
 INTO v_CVar1, v_CVar2
 FROM CUSTOMER
 WHERE CVAR1 = 5
 UNION ALL
 SELECT SVAR1, SVAR2
 INTO v_SVar1, v_SVar2
 FROM SALESMAN;

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Example ' || v_CVar1 || ' ' || v_SVar2);

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do so.

What you can do is the following:

```
 SELECT CVAR1, CVAR2
 INTO v_CVar1, v_CVar2
 FROM CUSTOMER
 WHERE CVAR1 = 5;

 SELECT SVAR1, SVAR2
 INTO v_SVar1, v_SVar2
 FROM SALESMAN;
```

Additionally, don't use `numeric` and `char`, it is much better to use `number` and `varchar2` instead if you have a choice.

If you want to still do it with `union` you will first of all need to use arrays, e.g. `dbms_sql.varchar2a` and `dbms_sql.number_table` data types correspondingly (or create your types) and use only one `bulk collect into` clause:

```
 SELECT CVAR1, CVAR2
 BULK COLLECT INTO array1, array2
 FROM CUSTOMER
 WHERE CVAR1 = 5
 UNION ALL
 SELECT SVAR1, SVAR2
 FROM SALESMAN;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
create table customer (
cus_id number(5),
cust_name varchar2(20)
);

insert into customer values(1,'Mahi');
insert into customer values(2,'Raja');

DECLARE
 v_CVar1 VARCHAR2(10); 
 v_CVar2 VARCHAR2(10);
Cursor C1 is
SELECT cus_id, cust_name FROM customer
UNION ALL 
SELECT cus_id, cust_name FROM customer; --Change table name
BEGIN
For rec in C1
Loop
 v_CVar1 := rec.cus_id;
 v_CVar2 := rec.cust_name;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Example : ' || ' ' ||  v_CVar1 || ' ' || v_CVar2 );
End Loop;
END;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Example :  1 Mahi
Example :  2 Raja
Example :  1 Mahi
Example :  2 Raja

Statement processed.
```